# Single Sign on in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sso

I have a application in sharepoint 2010.
Also There is an intranet application for my company which is not sharepoint.
I want something like , when the user enters our companies intranet application and click on the Sharepoint 2010 link.The user shouldnot be able to enter his/her credentials again.
How can this be accompanished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using active directory and normal Windows authentication, it's quite simple. Configure the sites as local intranet sites in Internet Explorer and users will be automatically logged on.

If not; you should specify what it is you're using as authentication mechanisms.

Comment: i am currently using ADFS mechanism.

Comment: Is the user logged in to the domain?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50516/active-directory-federation-services-and-sharepoint/50521#50521